# where am i going wrong ? Controlling gridview column value

Tags: c#, asp.net

`<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="Percent" ControlStyle-CssClass="hlink" HeaderText="% SEEN" ItemStyle-Width="6%" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="run.aspx?runId={0}" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true"/`>

The above is a column from my grid view.Lets call this column 'x'.

I am trying to control the value of x in .cs file as below:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[13].Text = "0%";
            return;
        }


        int p,q;
    GridViewRow item = e.Row;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring.ToString());
    string selectSQL = "  SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Count' FROM Analysed WHERE runId =@myvar group by runId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myvar", item.Cells[0].Text);
    SqlDataReader reader;
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        Int32.TryParse(item.Cells[8].Text, out p);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            Int32.TryParse( reader["Count"].ToString(),out q);
            item.Cells[13].Text =(q/p).ToString() + "%";

        }
        reader.Close();

    }


     }
```

I get an exception saying "An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values".This occurs in the lines :

```
if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[13].Text = "0%";
            return;
        }
```

Can anyone help ?

**EDIT :**

GridView Code :

```
 <asp:GridView ID = "GridView2" runat = "server" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            DataSourceID = "source" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"  AllowPaging="True"  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound">

                <Columns> 
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="runId" HeaderText = "RUN ID"  ControlStyle-CssClass="hlink" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="runanalysis.aspx?runId={0}" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataField="link" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" HeaderStyle-Font-Underline="true"  ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Family" HeaderText="Product Family" ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                 <asp:BoundField DataField = "Date"   DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yy}" ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField = "Number"  ItemStyle-Width="5%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField = "Total"  ItemStyle-Width="7%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Pass" ItemStyle-Width="7%" HeaderText="Pass Percent" DataFormatString="{0}%" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="pass"  ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="fail"  ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
                 <asp:BoundField DataField="Lang"  ItemStyle-Width="5%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Plat"  ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Flavor"  ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>
              <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="runId" DataTextField="Percent" ControlStyle-CssClass="hlink" HeaderText="% SEEN" ItemStyle-Width="6%" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="run.aspx?runId={0}" ItemStyle-Font-Underline="true"/>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="AutomationType" HeaderText ="Automation Type" ItemStyle-Width="7%"/>


                 </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The number of cells in `GridView2` are probably less than the cell you are trying to access. I think the number of `cells` (columns) are `13` and you have to use index,*12* instead of `13`. Its better to check the number of cells before accessing one of those.

```
if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 12 && e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Equals("0"))
{
      e.Row.Cells[12].Text = "0%";
      return;
}
```

**Edit** based on OP comments

You are trying to access the value that is not yet being assigned in RowDataBound event. In this event you can access the data item and parse it instead of parsing the control/cells.

*Change*

```
Int32.TryParse(item.Cells[8].Text, out p);
```

*To*

```
p = Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnFromDatabase"));
```

**Note:** *Same goes for other columns values.*

Comment: Hi Adil...I'll edit the question with the code for grid view also.I have started the count from 0

Comment: What line you get the exception?

Comment: I commented out : if (e.Row.Cells[8].Text.Equals("0"))
        {
            e.Row.Cells[13].Text = "0%";
            return;
        } The exception is now in :  Int32.TryParse(item.Cells[8].Text, out p);

Comment: any idea adil ? I have absolutely no clue on how to go about it

Comment: In Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnFromDatabase")); where do i write item.cells[8] ?

Comment: Yes, assign the result to p

Comment: But how will it know its item.cells[8] ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72808/discussion-between-user1698232-and-adil).